# forall equality in Coq

Tags: coq

I am trying to prove the following equality:

```
Lemma Foo (A : Type) (n : nat) (gen : forall p : nat, p < S n -> A)
(ic0 : 0 < S n) (ic1 : 0 mod S n < S n):
  gen (n - n) ic1 = gen 0 ic0.
```

The `n-n` is 0 by `Nat.sub_diag` and `0 mod S n` is also 0 by `Nat.mod_0_l`. However I could not easily apply these lemmas to types. I tried usual trick of `remember/rewrite/subst` but `subst` part fails:

```
   remember (gen (n-n)) as Q.
   remember (n-n) as Q1.
   rewrite Nat.sub_diag in HeqQ1.
   subst.
```

P.S. This question may use a better title. Please suggest.

Comment: I think the Coq library might have a proof of unicity of `lt n m` somewhere - and if not, I think I've seen it float by a couple times on coq-club so you might try searching the mailing list archives.  Then, you could generalize `ic0` and `ic1` which should hopefully allow for the rewriting.

Comment: not sure how to use unicity here. By the way, I am OK to use proof irrelevance, if that helps...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `subst` tactic fails because `remember` is buggy; I have reported this bug [here](https://coq.inria.fr/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=5784).  (As a sanity, check, finishing a goal with `abstract admit`, where `admit` comes from `Coq.Compat.AdmitAxiom`, should never fail with a type error.  If it does, that means there's a bug in Coq (or a plugin you're using).)

Here is a working proof (tested in 8.6.1 and 8.7+beta2):

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.

Lemma Foo (A : Type) (n : nat) (gen : forall p : nat, p < S n -> A)
      (ic0 : 0 < S n) (ic1 : 0 mod S n < S n):
  gen (n - n) ic1 = gen 0 ic0.
Proof.
  revert ic0 ic1; simpl; rewrite Nat.sub_diag; intros ic0 ic1.
  apply f_equal, le_unique.
Qed.
```

Note that you got lucky, in some sense, that `n - n` and `0 mod S n` are judgmentally equal.  Using `simpl` exposes this fact, and allows `rewrite` to work.